Salesforce native function to get the name of the host website
I have many websites with web-to-case integration, i need to discover wich one is sending some data into inapropriate format.
Into the Flow used to create the case, can i capture the name of the website? There is a Salesforce native function that can get the name of the host website?
Thank´s in advance.

this is typically done by using a hidden field on the web-to-case form that passes the the originating website into a custom field on Case

Simple and effective solution, thank you @cropredy

The typical solution for this is to create a hidden field on the web site form that maps a constant (the web site name) to a standard (I might use SuppliedName) or custom field on Case (W2C_Origin__c)
<input type=hidden name="nameofhiddenfield" id="nameofhiddenfield" value="XXXX">

You'll have to touch each of your web sites to do this
See Salesforce Pass hidden parameters in Web to Case and Web to Lead Help page. See the note about using custom fields wherein you have to pass the ID of the custom field instead of its API Name

thank you @cropredy

@AngeloRigo - if the answer solved your issue; it is helpful to the community if the answer is marked as accepted (see check mark). This way others can benefit.
